# How to Make a Dropdown In a Navbar Using CSS?

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having is that the Dropdown Does'nt Display on Hover.
Please can anyone tell me how can i make a dropdown using CSS.
I Have The Following Code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar > ul  {
    display: none;
}

.navbar > li:hover > ul {
    display: block; 
}

ul .navbar {
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navbar > li  a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Comic Sans Ms';
}

.navbar > li {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(gray,black);
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.navbar > li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: gray;
}
```

### JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aY5L6/

Comment: can you set up a codepen or fiddle for us?

Comment: Try following one of the many other questions / answers on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726176/having-trouble-making-drop-down-mean/22726206#22726206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your nested list structure. Move the closing `li` tag of the item **News** after the sub `ul` list like below.

```
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
```

Change this to below

```
<li><a href="#news">News</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

Also make the below css change

```
.navbar > ul  {
    display: none;
}
```

change the above to this

```
.navbar ul 
{
  display: none;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/TLgRP/)